# How to copy files from pod in one namespace to pod in another namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Does kubectl provide a way to copy files from pod in one namespace to another? I see we can copy files from pod to local machine and then copy them on another pod of different namespace. But can we copy directly from one namespace to another?

I tried:

`kubectl cp <namespace1>/<pod1>:/tmp/foo.txt <namespace2>/<pod1>:/tmp/foo.txt`

Looking at `kubectl cp` command help options I don't think there is any way to do that.

Answer (score 7):

Not really `kubectl cp` can only copy remote/local or local/remote, so unfortunately it's a 2 step process:

```
 $ kubectl cp <namespace1>/<pod1>:/tmp/foo.txt foo.txt
 $ kubectl cp foo.txt <namespace2>/<pod1>:/tmp/foo.txt
```

I would be nice to have a 1 step process, like [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/), but it is what it is as of this writing. I opened this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/551) to track it.

Comment: To save someone an extra click on a link, the linked issue above has been closed and will not be implemented.